# Formatted string hell - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, formatted

```
x = f'{1}{2}{3}'

a = "one"
b = "two"
c = "three"

#I want to print "onetwothree"
```

I don't even know how to explain this problem, I froze up every time I started typing anything into google. Haven't tried anything yet, since I don't even know where to start. Help.

Answer (score 4):

You can insert the variables' name inside the brackets of the f-string.

```
a = "one"
b = "two"
c = "three"

print(f'{a}{b}{c}')
>>> onetwothree
```

Comment: this answers my not so well formulated question. Basically, I  want to put the f'{1}{2}{3}' string at the beginning of the code and add in the variables as I go along some if/else statements. I could do it by hand but keeping in mind that I want the possinility of 3 or 4 variables per slot, it's just going to be a huge hassle. I understand this makes the question a million times more complicated, but I can't think of any other way to go about this issue

Comment: Then can you try to reformulate your question and make a clear example ?

Answer (score 1):

Put the variable names into the f-string.

```
print(f"{a}{b}{c}")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and keep in mind that this is not a discussion forum, but a Q&A site; as such, there are certain requirements for questions, and it is not appropriate to answer questions that don't meet those requirements. If you want to help people with whatever random coding problems (including "I have multiple problems with this code, please debug it for me"), without heed to the format, it would be better to try Reddit or Quora.

Comment: Sorry, still learning the ropes here.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = f'{1}{2}{3}'

a = "one"
b = "two"
c = "three"

#I want to print "onetwothree"
print(f"{a}{b}{c}")
```

[image]

Explanation: for every variable `x`, you fill in with `{x}`. For python 3, you use the `print(item)` function if you want to print out an item.

*The print() function prints the specified message to the screen, or other standard output device.
The message can be a string, or any other object, the object will be converted into a string before written to the screen.*